# How to preserve output format of Powershell commands that are executed from an object?

Tags: command-line, powershell, pipelining

### Scenario

I would like to see the output of powershell commands that are executed inside a method of an object, in the same way I see them "live/when they are happening" when they are not inside the object.

### Examples

To illustrate the undesired difference, I will show 2 scripts, the first one shows the output of the commnad, the 2nd does not. Both are run by opening powershell, browsing to their directory and ran with `./<scriptname>.ps1`

1. Consider `scriptA.ps1`with content:

```
lxrun /install /y
```

Which produces the desired outcome of:

> ```
> Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows
> Subsystem for Linux distribution. Distributions can be installed by
> visiting the Windows Store: https://aka.ms/wslstore
>
> This will install Ubuntu on Windows, distributed by Canonical and
> licensed under its terms available here: https://aka.ms/uowterms
>
> The legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution is already
> installed.
> ```

2. `scriptB.ps1` with content:

```
# runs single command
Class Object{
    runCommand(){
        lxrun /install /y
    }
}

# create object
[Object] $object = [Object]::new()

# execute command in method runCommand() of [Object] object
$object.runCommand()
```

Which does not show any output at all.

### Attempts

All attempts are made inside the following script, at line: `<command here>`

```
# runs single command
Class Object{
    runCommand(){
        `<command here>`
    }
}
```

1. Line:

```
Write-Output (lxrun /install /y)
```

Resulting output:(no output)

> 

2. Line:

```
Write-Host (lxrun /install /y)
```

Resulting output:Correct content, but lost/changed legible text formatting:

> ```
> W a r n i n g :   l x r u n . e x e   i s   o n l y   u s e d   t o  
> c o n f i g u r e   t h e   l e g a c y   W i n d o w s   S u b s y s
> t e m   f o r   L i n u x   d i s t r i b u t i o n .       D i s t r
> i b u t i o n s   c a n   b e   i n s t a l l e d   b y   v i s i t i
> n g   t h e   W i n d o w s   S t o r e :       h t t p s : / / a k a
> . m s / w s l s t o r e             T h i s   w i l l   i n s t a l l 
> U b u n t u   o n   W i n d o w s ,   d i s t r i b u t e d   b y   C
> a n o n i c a l   a n d   l i c e n s e d   u n d e r   i t s   t e r
> m s   a v a i l a b l e   h e r e :         h t t p s : / / a k a . m
> s / u o w t e r m s             T h e   l e g a c y   W i n d o w s  
> S u b s y s t e m   f o r   L i n u x   d i s t r i b u t i o n   i s 
> a l r e a d y   i n s t a l l e d .
> ```

3. Line:

```
Write-Host (lxrun /install /y) | Out-Host
```

Resulting output: same as in attempt 2.

4. Line:

```
Write-Host (lxrun /install /y) | Out-Default
```

Resulting output: same as in attempt 2.

5. Line:

```
Write-Host (lxrun /install /y) | Out-String
```

Resulting output: same as in attempt 2

6. Line:

```
write-verbose (lxrun /install /y)
```

Resulting output:(no output)

> ```
> Write-Verbose : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Message'.
> Specified method is not supported.
> At F:\path to example script\example.ps1:30 char:23
> +         write-verbose (lxrun /install /y)
> +                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Verbose], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteVerboseCommand
> ```

7. Line:

```
write-verbose (lxrun /install /y) -Verbose
```

Resulting output:same as in 6 (except when the line at which the error occurs, the -Verbose is included)

> 

8. Line:

```
(lxrun /install /y) | Write-Host
```

Resulting output: Better readible but still not the nor

> ````
> o   c o n f i g u r e   t h e   l e g a c y  W i n d o w s   S u b s y
> s t e m   f o r   L i n u x   d i s t r i b u t i o n .
>
>
>  D i s t r i b u t i o n s   c a n   b e   i n s t a l l e d   b y   v
> i s i t i n g   t h e   W i n d o w s   S t o r e :
>
>
>  h t t p s : / / a k a . m s / w s l s t o r e
>
>
>
>
>
>  T h i s   w i l l   i n s t a l l   U b u n t u   o n   W i n d o w s
> ,   d i s t r i b u t e d   b y   C a n o n i c a l   a n d   l i c e
> n s e d   u n d e r   i t s   t e r m s   a v a i l a b l e   h e r e
> :
>
>
>  h t t p s : / / a k a . m s / u o w t e r m s
>
>
>
>
>
>  T h e   l e g a c y   W i n d o w s   S u b s y s t e m   f o r   L i
> n u x   d i s t r i b u t i o n   i s   a l r e a d y   i n s t a l l
> e d . ```
> ````

9. Line:

```
Write-Verbose -Message (lxrun /install /y)
```

Resulting output:

```
Write-Verbose : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Message'. Specified method is not supported.
At G:/path to file\example.ps1:35 char:32
 +         Write-Verbose -Message (lxrun /install /y)
 +                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Verbose], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteVerboseCommand
```

10. Line:

```
Write-Verbose -Message lxrun /install /y
```

Resulting output: same as in attempt 9

11. Line:

```
Write-Verbose -Message (lxrun /install /y) -Verbose
```

Resulting output: same as in attempt 9 (except when the line at which the error occurs, the -Verbose is included)

12. Based on [the question and answers linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469821/powershell-script-support-for-verbose), I modified the script to:

```
# runs single command

#[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
Class Object{    
    runCommand(){
        lxrun /install /y|Write-Verbose
    }
}

# create object
[Object] $object = [Object]::new()

# execute command in method runCommand() of [Object] object
$object.runCommand()
```

which is called with the -Verbose parameter when running it: `./example.ps1 -Verbose`. It returns a black and yellow text:

> ```
> VERBOSE: W a r n i n g :   l x r u n . e x e   i s   o n l y   u s e d   t o   >c o n f i g u r e   t h e
> l e g a c y   W i n d o w s   S u b s y s t e m   f o r   L i n u x   d i s t >r i b u t i o n .
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:  D i s t r i b u t i o n s   c a n   b e   i n s t a l l e d   b y   v >i s i t i n g   t h e
> W i n d o w s   S t o r e :
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:  h t t p s : / / a k a . m s / w s l s t o r e
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:  T h i s   w i l l   i n s t a l l   U b u n t u   o n   W i n d o w s >,   d i s t r i b u t e d
> b y   C a n o n i c a l   a n d   l i c e n s e d   u n d e r   i t s   t e r >m s   a v a i l a b l e
> h e r e :
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:  h t t p s : / / a k a . m s / u o w t e r m s
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:  T h e   l e g a c y   W i n d o w s   S u b s y s t e m   f o r   L i >n u x
> d i s t r i b u t i o n   i s   a l r e a d y   i n s t a l l e d .
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> VERBOSE:
> ```

Where from what I understood the `Param()` is included to pass/absorb the `-Verbose` argument, and the `[CmdletBinding()]` [enables let binding the way a `cmdlet` does it, instead of the "normal" way a script does.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdletbindingattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=pscore-6.2.0) I still need to understand what that difference is/means. And the the formatting is not yet correct/desired with this Write-Verbose implementation.

### Question

How do I write the output of a command on the powershell terminal without delay, without losing it's original formatting (as with `scriptA.ps1`)?

### Note

One could build a parser, but I think there might be more efficient and faster solutions which I have not yet found.

Comment: So which instance generated the output? The one with `Write-Host`or the one with `Write-Output`? One Option would be to use [`Write-Verbose`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-6).

Comment: @Seth I apologize for the unclarity, I have restructured the attempts which show that the `Write-Host` option generated outputs at attempts 3,4,5,8 (In a "wrong"/different formatting), while the `Write-Output` at attempt 1, did not generate an output.Thank you for your suggestion, I incorporated the results of the attempts in the initial question, and will proceed debugging their respective error messages.

Comment: `Write-Verbose` didn't produce any output because you didn't change `$VerbosePreference` and actually made sure that you're [supporting `-Verbose` for your class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469821/powershell-script-support-for-verbose). [about_Classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-6) also points out that using Write-Host essentially violates PowerShell principals and why you're not seeing any output by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out writing a parser was a faster(building wise, not [necessarily] runtime-wise) solution, as my search procedure did not (yet) look into why and how the commands with `write..` etc., changed the output (format).

```
# runs single command
Class Object{
    runCommand(){
        $output = (lxrun /install /y)
        Write-Host $this.parseOutput($output) # return formating back to "normal"
    }

    # removes null characters and then replaces triple spaces with enters.
    [String] parseOutput([String] $output){

        # first remove all nulls
        $output = $output.Replace(([char]0).ToString(),'')

        # then replace all triple occurrences of spaces with newlines
        $output = $output.Replace(([char]32+[char]32+[char]32).ToString(),"`n")

        return $output
    }

}

# create object
[Object] $object = [Object]::new()

# execute command in method runCommand() of [Object] object
$object.runCommand()
```

This "solves"/remedies the problem, but I prefer deeper understanding.Hence, if anyone can explain:

1. Why the extra `null` and `space` characters are added when a command is executed from/in an object I would greatly appreciate it.
2. How it can be done in the same line as the command, without calling a self-written method, a better solution is found.

Comment: They probably didn't change the output format. You're simply running a non PowerShell command so you can run into encoding issues. Using [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) might help in that situation. Also using `Write-Host` is usually a bad idea. You really might want to use something like `Write-Verbose` or simply return the output from the command.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborations, could you perhaps specify how one could "return the output from the command"?

Comment: By using a return statement, just like you do in your other method that returns `$output`. By returning that you would be able to ... well, return the output of the command.